# Imunnity Debugger PyCommands: failed to locate main function

Tags: python-2.7

relatively simple question here.  I recently installed immunity debugger for the PyCommands feature, however whenever I try to write my own pycommand and execute it in immunity, it gives me the error message "failed to locate main function".  Odd, considering I did write a main(args) function.  The code I tried to use was as follows:

```
#!usr/bin/env python

from immlib import *

def main(args):
    imm = Debugger()
    return "[*] Command successfully executed."
```

I cannot see what is wrong with this, as I have only been following the example scripts included with Immunity.  I have also checked !list which shows my command on a list of available commands, but when I try to run it from there, it still throws the error.  Does anyone know why this might be?

OS: Windows XP SP3 x86 (VMWare)

Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 3):

So I just figured out my own problem.  The name of the command was 'test'.  I'm guessing test was a reserved word or something, because I renamed it to mycommand and got the desired output.  If anyone else comes across this issue with immunity, I hope this helps.